# Node.js open terminal window (Electron on Mac OS)

Tags: node.js, macos, terminal, electron, osascript

I have an electron application that I would like to open a terminal (cmd window), and run a script within the terminal on the click of a button. I have tried a few options such as

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
```

However this only runs within the application and doesn't launch an external terminal window. I have also tried

```
var osascript = require('osascript');
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "./hello.py'
```

However this simply give me the error 'SyntaxError: Unexpected string' and doesn't launch an external terminal.

If anyone has the solution please help me out, as I've been struggling for a while.

Thanks

Comment: you're missing a " at the end of .py